# bind both squid and proxy

Tags: iptables, squid

```
192.168.10.1 bind both squid on port 3128 and httpd on port 1000
```

how to serve both port as client request on port 80 at the same time

like this for redirect all request on port 80 to 3128

```
iptables -t nat -A PREROUTING -i eth0 -p tcp --dport 80 -j DNAT --to-destination 192.168.10.1:3128
```

but how to redirect only when client request external address not proxy server it self

Is there any syntext like this?

```
iptables -t nat -A PREROUTING -i eth0 -p tcp (except server ip it self)  --dport 80 -j DNAT --to-destination 192.168.10.1:3128

iptables -t nat -A PREROUTING -i eth0 -p tcp -d ! 192.168.10.1 --dport 80 -j DNAT --to-destination 192.168.10.1:3128
```

thank you.

Comment: This should be in **ServerFault** or **SuperUser** or **Unix&Linux**, not StackOverflow.

Answer (score 0):

I found it.

```
iptables -t nat -A PREROUTING ! --destination 192.168.10.1 -s 192.168.10.18 -p tcp --dport 80 -j DNAT --to-destination 192.168.10.1:3128
```

and binding httpd to port 1000

```
iptables -t nat -A PREROUTING -d 192.168.10.1 -s 192.168.10.7 -p tcp --dport 80 -j DNAT --to-destination 192.168.10.1:1000
```

It's work but I don't know it is the right way or not.

Comment: @njai do you want to apply the rule to only 2 clients? because that's what happens if you use `-s`. drop the `-s a.b.c.d` part. another problem is that the reply will be sent back directly to the client, so it *shouldn't* work, but since you said it's working...